# parallelization in R with execution times worst than serial

Tags: r, parallel-processing, benchmarking

I have a task to select days from weeks randomly. For this I have written two functions: one using a simple `for` loop and the other using function `mclapply` from package `parallel`. The results of micro benchmark are most of the time worst for the `mclapply` implementation than that of the `for` loop.
Here is the code:

```
#######################
###load packages
#######################
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse)
p_load(lubridate)
p_load(chron)
p_load(parallel)
p_load(microbenchmark)

DCA_scheduler<-function(start_dt=as.Date("2014-01-01"),end_date=ymd('2021-10-07'),by=1){
  ###df with dates to set DCA dates
  date_df<-data.frame(Date=seq(start_dt,end_date, by = '1 day'))
  
  date_df$weekday <- date_df$Date %>% wday(label =T) %>% factor(labels=c("sun","mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat"))
  date_df$year<-date_df$Date %>% year() %>% factor()
  date_df$week<-date_df$Date %>% isoweek() %>% factor()
  date_df$year_week<-paste0(date_df$year,"-",date_df$week) %>% {factor(.,levels=unique(.),ordered=T)} %>% as.numeric()
 start_week<-date_df[date_df$Date %in% start_dt,"year_week"]
 start_wkday<-date_df[date_df$Date %in% start_dt,"weekday"] %>% as.character()
 
 wbdca<-by
 #weeks to sample.
 last_yw<-max(date_df$year_week)
 weeks_DCA<-seq(start_week,last_yw,by=wbdca)
 DCA_dts_ls<-list()
 ##sample first day of week:
 DCA_dts_ls[[start_week]]<-date_df[date_df$year_week %in% start_week & date_df$weekday >=start_wkday,] %>% {.[sample(1:nrow(.),1),]}

 ###using for - sequential approach
 for(i in weeks_DCA[-1]){
    DCA_dts_ls[[i]]<-date_df[date_df$year_week %in% i,] %>% {.[sample(1:nrow(.),1),]}
    }
 #final result:
 DCA_dts_df<- DCA_dts_ls %>% reduce(rbind)
 return(DCA_dts_df)
}


DCA_scheduler_prl<-function(start_dt=as.Date("2014-01-01"),end_date=ymd('2021-10-07'),by=1){
  ###df with dates to set DCA dates
  date_df<-data.frame(Date=seq(start_dt,end_date, by = '1 day'))
  
  date_df$weekday <- date_df$Date %>% wday(label =T) %>% factor(labels=c("sun","mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat"))
  date_df$year<-date_df$Date %>% year() %>% factor()
  date_df$week<-date_df$Date %>% isoweek() %>% factor()
  date_df$year_week<-paste0(date_df$year,"-",date_df$week) %>% {factor(.,levels=unique(.),ordered=T)} %>% as.numeric()
 start_week<-date_df[date_df$Date %in% start_dt,"year_week"]
 start_wkday<-date_df[date_df$Date %in% start_dt,"weekday"] %>% as.character()

 wbdca<-by
 #weeks to sample.
 last_yw<-max(date_df$year_week)
 weeks_DCA<-seq(start_week,last_yw,by=wbdca)
 DCA_dts_ls<-list()
 ##sample first day of week:
 DCA_dts_ls[[start_week]]<-date_df[date_df$year_week %in% start_week & date_df$weekday >=start_wkday,] %>% {.[sample(1:nrow(.),1),]}

 ###using mclapply - parallel approach
 DCA_dts_ls2<-mclapply(weeks_DCA[-1], function(x){date_df[date_df$year_week %in% x,] %>% {.[sample(1:nrow(.),1),]}},mc.cores=8)
 DCA_dts_ls<-append(DCA_dts_ls,DCA_dts_ls2)
 #final result:
 DCA_dts_df<- DCA_dts_ls %>% reduce(rbind)
 return(DCA_dts_df)
}

microbenchmark(DCA_scheduler_prl(), DCA_scheduler(), times=10)
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
 DCA_scheduler_prl() 324.8263 336.0000 364.0848 348.9240 367.7543 456.3611
     DCA_scheduler() 307.0109 311.4461 325.2401 318.1286 327.0308 374.1800
 neval
    10
    10
```

I am in a laptop with a cpu with 8 cores available. I am new to this, but is it normal for this type of task to get worst performance in the parallel approach than in the serial one?

Could it be possible that the tasks are to short and the amount of messages between workers and master is affecting the performance?

I have tried another approaches using `foreach` and `doParallel` with even worst results.

Comment: Hi,  if the task is too short, assigning task to each core +  performing the task could take more time than doing the task sequentially.  This is depending on the library you are using (I've never used that one). I would reccomend you to try to do the comparison with more data and see if parallel becomes faster than sequential

Comment: Parallelization tends to be a great option when computation time (far) exceeds time to transfer data between cores/processes and the coordination of tasks. In your real-world use-case, are you able to subset your data so that you can do a parallel-vs-serial test over (say) an hour instead of weeks?

Comment: @r2evans the thing is that the task that I am trying to parallelize is just sampling a day in a given week, so as you said, the computing time (sampling a day in a week) is very small compared with times of transfer between cores. It seem then that this problem cannot improve its times with a parallel approach.

Comment: Sure, but still ... data-transfer (while very low here) and process-management combine to an overhead that is negating any benefits of parallelization. For something such as sampling days of weeks, it is *far* faster to keep it in one process.